# XWiki cannot start server after it was stopped

Tags: docker, xwiki

I have experiencing issue with `XWiki` when I shut it down and then try to restart. First I'm copying `docker-compose.yml` from official repo:

https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-postgres.yml

Then I run it with:

```
docker-compose up
```

So far so good. System is up and running and I create admin/admin credential user. Then I choose to leave empty wiki. Everything seems to work so far.

Then I decided (I tested two scenarios and both work same - after installing some extensions I would like to use and without installing any extensions) to shut it down. So I open second terminal tab and type:

```
docker-compose stop
```

This leads to stack trace that is over 2000 line long. I paste some of it at the end.

Bottom line is that after I `docker-compose up` it again there is line about starting Solr Embedded server but never reaching to the line where server tells that it started (first start has such line) - it seems to hang indefinitely. Only way to start is to destroy persistent storage but obviously that's not an option for production...

Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

```
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:58.411 INFO [Thread-33] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:58.412 INFO [Thread-33] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 12:26:58,745 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.x.o.i.s.DefaultOfficeServer  - Open Office instance stopped. 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.015 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.017 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxSchedulerPurge-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.018 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.019 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [searcherExecutor-10-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.020 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [OfficeProcessThread-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |  java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.021 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@95277eb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.024 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@7cb58068]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.026 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@bbf4311]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.028 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@11c890a2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.033 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@296e007d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 12:26:59,037 [extendion.index job group daemon thread - org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob@71121611([extension, index])] ERROR .o.i.DefaultObservationManager - Failed to send event [org.xwiki.job.event.JobFinishedEvent@451d35ff] to listener [org.xwiki.eventstream.internal.UntypedEventListener@37d71d15] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get [role = [interface org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentManager] hint = [wiki]]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.GenericProvider.get(GenericProvider.java:103)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.eventstream.internal.UntypedEventListener.onEvent(UntypedEventListener.java:128)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.notify(DefaultObservationManager.java:320)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.notify(DefaultObservationManager.java:291)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.jobFinished(AbstractJob.java:335)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.job.internal.AbstractExtensionJob.jobFinished(AbstractExtensionJob.java:134)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.runInContext(AbstractJob.java:248)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:220)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.tryInstall(ExtensionIndexJob.java:480)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateExtension(ExtensionIndexJob.java:350)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:554)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateLastExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:233)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.runInternal(ExtensionIndexJob.java:216)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.runInContext(AbstractJob.java:243)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:220)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Can't find descriptor for the component with type [interface org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentManager] and hint [wiki]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:212)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.GenericProvider.getInstance(GenericProvider.java:111)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.GenericProvider.get(GenericProvider.java:100)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     ... 17 common frames omitted
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.034 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@798873f8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 12:26:59,040 [extendion.index job group daemon thread - org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob@71121611([extension, index])] ERROR o.x.e.i.i.j.ExtensionIndexJob  - Failed to validate extension with if [pbas:reinit_sandbox] on namespace [null] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: extension_index
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:197)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:211)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:177)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:138)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:156)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.ExtensionIndexStore.add(ExtensionIndexStore.java:476)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.ExtensionIndexStore.updateCompatible(ExtensionIndexStore.java:357)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateExtension(ExtensionIndexJob.java:361)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:554)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateLastExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:233)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.runInternal(ExtensionIndexJob.java:216)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.runInContext(AbstractJob.java:243)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:220)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 12:26:59.042 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@49f7d14e]) and a value of type [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo] (value [org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.core.MatchedInfo@4725207]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 12:26:59,043 [extendion.index job group daemon thread - org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob@71121611([extension, index])] ERROR .o.i.DefaultObservationManager - Failed to send event [org.xwiki.job.event.status.StartStepProgressEvent@e41ea28] to listener [org.xwiki.eventstream.internal.UntypedEventListener@37d71d15] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get [role = [interface org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentManager] hint = [wiki]]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.GenericProvider.get(GenericProvider.java:103)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.eventstream.internal.UntypedEventListener.onEvent(UntypedEventListener.java:128)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.notify(DefaultObservationManager.java:320)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.notify(DefaultObservationManager.java:291)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.internal.DefaultJobProgressManager.startStep(DefaultJobProgressManager.java:84)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.internal.DefaultJobProgressManager.startStep(DefaultJobProgressManager.java:72)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:548)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.validateLastExtensions(ExtensionIndexJob.java:233)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.extension.index.internal.job.ExtensionIndexJob.runInternal(ExtensionIndexJob.java:216)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.runInContext(AbstractJob.java:243)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:220)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Can't find descriptor for the component with type [interface org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentManager] and hint [wiki]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |     at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:212)
```

--- EDIT ---

Here is log after `docker-compose up` when running 2nd+ time (persistent storage is already created and used). Log is incomplete in a sense that it looks like server hangs on Solr startup (I have waited up to 10 minutes).

```
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |   Synchronizing config file hibernate.cfg.xml...
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |   Synchronizing config file xwiki.cfg...
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web |   Synchronizing config file xwiki.properties...
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.64
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.468 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 4 2021 23:14:16 UTC
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.471 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.64.0
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.473 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-78-generic
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.473 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.474 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.10+9
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            AdoptOpenJDK
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.478 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.482 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.483 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.485 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.488 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.500 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.501 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.26] using APR version [1.6.5].
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.501 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.501 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.515 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.635 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.700 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1571 ms
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.912 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.64
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 12-Mar-2021 13:42:04.948 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:14,867 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  iPropertiesConfigurationSource - Loading [xwiki.properties] from [file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/xwiki.properties] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:15,248 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.x.e.i.ServletEnvironment     - Using permanent directory [/usr/local/xwiki/data] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:27,906 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.x.s.s.i.EmbeddedSolr         - Starting embedded Solr server... 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:27,913 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.x.s.s.i.EmbeddedSolr         - Using Solr home directory: [/usr/local/xwiki/data/store/solr] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:30,029 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.e.j.u.s.S.config             - Trusting all certificates configured for Client@75672745[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:30,029 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.e.j.u.s.S.config             - No Client EndPointIdentificationAlgorithm configured for Client@75672745[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:30,580 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.e.j.u.s.S.config             - Trusting all certificates configured for Client@2ea75ff9[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:30,581 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.e.j.u.s.S.config             - No Client EndPointIdentificationAlgorithm configured for Client@2ea75ff9[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null] 
xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web | 2021-03-12 13:42:30,657 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.a.s.c.CoreContainer          - Not all security plugins configured!  authentication=disabled authorization=disabled.  Solr is only as secure as you make it. Consider configuring authentication/authorization before exposing Solr to users internal or external.  See https://s.apache.org/solrsecurity for more info
```

Comment: I have experiencing some lock issues with containerized Xwiki that has been stopped... Could you paste the logs you get when you launch again `docker-compose up`?

Comment: @mtovmassian I have edited question and added what you have requested.

Comment: Not so much clues... What if you clean everything under `/usr/local/xwiki/data/store/solr`?

Comment: @mtovmassian That seems to help. Official docker-compose use named volumes, so path is: `var/lib/docker/volumes/<project_name>_xwiki-data/_data/data/store/solr` so if I run `rm -rf` with this path as argument server does start. My guess is/was `Solr` is forcibly shutdown and that crashes it's internal data structures.

Idk if `XWiki` handle this but `Gerrit` seems to had similar issue in the past. I think they solved it by using `JVM Shutdown Hooks`.

Any way I will temporary do fix to remove this directory upon startup if exists just in case until this might be fixed.